# Which config files do I hack to deploying concrete5 on appfog

Tags: php, mysql, concrete5, appfog

I am trying to deploy concrete5 on appfog.com
But cannot use the concrete5 wizzard(front end gui to set it up) as appfog does not provide the mysql details. It gives it in terms of an environment variable (refer to - https://docs.appfog.com/services/mysql#php)

I configured the config/site.php with the following, what other files do I need to configure to get concrete5 up and running.

Config/site.php

```
    <?php 
    define('DB_SERVER', 'mysql.xxx.com');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'sidharthmadan');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'thisIsThePass');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'c5db');
    define('PASSWORD_SALT','fGtuyHhYrsn6865Gk7b8bho09HV6h');
    define('AVATAR_NONE', ASSETS_URL_IMAGES . '/spacer.gif');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have to edit any other files, but you may need to change the folder permissions of files/, config/, packages/ to writable.

More details here:

http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/installation/installing_concrete5/

Comment: I will change the permissions to writable. But am still a bit confused about the password salt, do I just make up anything or there is a set procedure to get it.

Comment: The password salt should be a random string, so in essence, yes, you can make up anything.  It's an extra layer of security for your passwords.  In theory, if anybody steals your database of user passwords, they'll still need to know your password salt to be able to crack your passwords.